# XSLT transformation to remove "-' from input

Tags: xslt

I need your help in transforming a input value by removing "-' from it.

In my request I am getting data like 123456-2345 and in target system I need to publish it by removing "-" from it like 1234562345.

I need to do this using xslt transformation . Could someone please suggest me how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you are doing you could use xsl translate:

```
<xsl:variable name="deleteable">-</xsl:variable>
<xsl:value-of select="translate($value, $deleteable,'')"/>
```

Comment: Thanks. Just one quick question. Instead of creating a new variable cant we do same in translate function ?

Comment: Yes. That was just a copy/paste of some code I've used in the past.